# PassEye или "Парольный глаз" (показываем пароль в textBox)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-webforms, javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше реализовать кнопку "подглядывания" введенных символов пароля.

Пытаюсь сделать используя эту [рекомендацию](http://sadisme.ru/jscoding/45-passeye-ili-parolnyy-glaz-pokazyvaem-parol-v-input.html), но почему то если запихнуть в `<span>` textBox, то при нажатии на глаз ничего не происходит.

```
<span class="passEye">
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="30" Width="152" TabIndex="2" />
</span>
```

А если реализовать так :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="30" Width="152" TabIndex="2" />
<div onclick="passEye();">click</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passEye() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>').type == 'password')
            document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>').type = 'test';
        else document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>').type = 'password';
    }
</script>
```

То такая реализация не работает в IE.

Методами тыка было реализован скрипт:

```
<div onclick="passEye(document.getElementById();">click</div>
            
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passEye(document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>')) {
    var marker = $('<span />').insertBefore(document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>'));
    if (document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>').type == 'password') {
    $(document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>')).detach().attr('type', 'text').insertAfter(marker).focus();
    marker.remove();
    } else {
    $(document.getElementById('<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>')).detach().attr('type', 'password').insertAfter(marker).focus();
    marker.remove();
    }
}
</script>
```

Теперь у меня есть скрипт, который реализовывает моргание глаза :

```
$(function () {
    //PassEye by SaD(im-sad@ya.ru)

    $(".passEye").append('<span class="eye" title="Показать/скрыть пароль"></span>');

    $(".passEye .eye").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('openEye');        
    });   
});
```

И мой скрипт, который реализовывает преобразование пароля.

Вопрос: Как мне их соеденить?
Как мне перенести мой скрипт, так, чтобы при нажатии на глаз выполнялось преоброзование пароля?

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет эта статья: http://wsnippets.com/instant-show-hide-password-jquery/  

Посмотреть демо можно тут: http://wsnippets.com/demo/bootstrap-show-hide-password/

Comment: Там чтобы скачать библиотеку, нужно подписаться на рассылку автора. но мейл не аццептится... 
Я использую что-то похожее по реализации в приведенной ссылке вверху, но почему-то оно не работает(((

Answer (score 0):

*Вот так можно реализовать **кнопку "подглядывания"***

```css
.e-input-eye:before {
  content: '\e345';
  font-family: e-icons;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #8A2336 !important;
}

.e-input-eye:active:before {
  content: '\e721';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/20.4.48/ej2-icons/styles/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/20.4.48/ej2-icons/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group mb-2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="@typeParolKnopka" name="" class="form-control input_pass" @bind-value="userPassword" placeholder="введите пароль">
  <span class='e-icons e-input-eye input-group-text' @onclick="ShowPasswordFunction"></span>
</div>
```

в `фрагмент кода` для демонстрации `C#` не вставишь, поэтому ниже код логики для самой кнопки, чтоб показать или скрыть символы пароля

```
public string typeParolKnopka { get; set; } = "password";
public void ShowPasswordFunction()
{
    if (this.typeParolKnopka == "password")
    {
        this.typeParolKnopka = "text";
    }
    else
    {
        this.typeParolKnopka = "password";
    }
}
```

[а вот в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513929/%D0%98%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C) я пытаюсь подправить дизайн глаза, чтоб иконка менялась, когда пароль показывает/прячет == открытый/закрытый